# Dynamic form fields on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which has dynamic fields, they are added by clicking Add button:

```
$scope.addField = function() {
            $scope.fields.push($sce.trustAsHtml($('#form_fields').data('prototype')))
        };
```

The template is this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="field in fields">
        <div ng-bind-html="field"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the prototype goes like this:

```
<div id="form_fields" data-prototype="<input ng-model="data['field_name'][unique_index]" type="text">" > </div>
```

dont mind the quotes, they are escaped, and everything works fine with adding the fields.
The problem is that `data['field_name'][unique_index]` is unknown to Angular when added dynamicly, and only the static fields are submitted.

How do I make these new ng-model variables visible to Angular?

Comment: try $apply. Probably outside digest.

Comment: where should I put it? it allways gives me errors :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago. The issue is that ngModel can only crete new data structures when represented in dot notation (`foo.bar.baz`) not array notation. To get around this, I created the `ng-model-create` directive. It will evaluate an expression like the one you have and convert the `ng-model` attribute value to dot notation (while remembering the original expression).

https://gist.github.com/jessehouchins/c073565f6b693877191a

So, using this, your inout would look like `<input ng-model-create ng-model="data['field_name'][unique_index]" type="text">`.

Comment: your script does what it supposed to do just on static fields, but not on dynamic ones. And btw ngModel not only can but it also does create data structures from array notations.